# Django - cannot pass error message to context

Tags: python, django

I have a view responsible for inviting users to note:

```
def invite_user(request, pk):
    note = get_object_or_404(Note, pk=pk)
    form = InviteUser()
    err = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InviteUser(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() and username != request.user.username and not Note.objects.filter(members__contains = [username], id=note.id):
                notification = Notification(message=f"Do you want to join to {User.objects.get(username=note.user)}'s note: {note.title}?", user=User.objects.get(username=username), note_id=note.id)
                notification.save()
            else:
                print('Error')
                err = True

            return redirect('show', pk=note.id)

    if err:
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'error': 'You cannot invite this user!'
        }

        return render(request, context)
    else:
        context = {
            'form': form,
        }

        return render(request, context)
```

Template:

```
    {% if error %}
        <h1>{{ error }}</h1>
    {% endif %}
```

When I pass correct user invitation is sent, but when there is error I see print in console, but there is not `h1` with error in templete. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was easier than I thought it will be.
Solution was adding this line to view:

```
messages.error(request, 'Error')
```

and this code to template:

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```